# Angular 2: how to get directive attributes using nativeElement

Tags: angular

I need to access the directive attributes in lightbox.directive.ts. I want to use nativeElement because I need to get the coordinates of elements using .getBoundingClientRect(). Within one directive, I would like to access instances of the remaining directives. Therefore, in the example, I pass the link to #images as the parameter [lightboxImages] = "images".

Thank you.

**app.component.html**

```
<div #images>

    <img *ngFor="let image of myImages" 
        [src]="image.path" 
        lightbox
        [lightboxImages]="images"
        [fullImagePath]="image.fullImagePath" />
</div>
```

**lightbox.directive.ts**

```
export class LightboxDirective {
    index; // any image index
    @Input() images; 
    @Input() fullImagePath;  

    get thumbnailImage(){
        return this.images.getElementsByTagName("img")[this.index];
    }

    get thumbnailImagePosition(){
        return this.thumbnailImage.getBoundingClientRect();
    }

    get thumbnailImageFullPath(){
        return this.thumbnailImage['attributes']['fullImagePath']; // ? 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can inject `ElementRef` into your directive, it is the reference to the element on which you added your directive.

You can then access the native element:

```
constructor(elementRef: ElementRef) {
    this.nativeElement = this.elementRef.nativeElement;
}
```

You can consider creating another 'container' directive which injects all `LightboxDirective`s and manages them. You can inject all directives of specific type in your 'container' directive:

```
@ContentChildren(LightboxDirective, { descendants: true })
lightboxes: QueryList<LightboxDirective>;
```

Comment: Thank you. Within one directive, I would like to access instances of the remaining directives. Therefore, in the example, I pass the link to #images as the parameter [lightboxImages] = "images".